# Why does Keras to_categorical method not return 3-D tensor when inputting 2-D tensor?

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, keras, lstm, pos-tagger

I was trying to build a LSTM neural net with Keras to predict tags for words in a set of sentences.

The implementation is all pretty straight forward, but the surprising thing was that

- given the exactly same and otherwise correctly implemented code and
- using Tensorflow 1.4.0 with Keras running on Tensorflow Backend,

on some people's computers, it returned tensors with wrong dimensions, while for others it worked perfectly.

The problem occured in the following context:

First, we turned the list of training sentences (sentences as a list of word indeces) into a 2-D matrix using the `pad_sequences` method from Keras (https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/):

```
def do_padding(sequences, length, padding_value):
    return pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=length, padding='post',           
    truncating='post', value=padding_value)

train_sents_padded = do_padding(train_sents, MAX_LENGTH,                                             
word_to_id[PAD_TOKEN])
```

Next, we used our do_padding method on the corresponding training labels to turn them into a padded matrix. At the same time, we used the Keras `to_categorical` method (https://keras.io/utils/#to_categorical) to add a one-hot encoded vector to the  created label matrix (one one-hot vector for each cell in the matrix, that means for word in each training sentence):

```
train_labels_padded = to_categorical(do_padding(train_labels, MAX_LENGTH,     
label_to_id["O"]), NUM_LABELS)
```

We expected the resulting shape to be 3-D: *(len(train_labels), MAX_LENGTH, NUM_LABELS)*. Yet, we found that the resulting shape was 2-D and basically looked like this: *((len(train_labels) x MAX_LENGTH), NUM_LABELS)*, meaning the numbers on the two expected dimensions *len(train_labels)* and *MAX_LENGTH* were multiplied and flattened into one dimension.

Interestingly, this problem as said before only occured for about 50% of the people, using Tensorflow 1.4.0 and Keras running on Tensorflow Backend.

We managed to solve the problem by reshaping the label matrix manually:

```
train_labels_padded = np.reshape(train_labels_padded, (len(train_labels),   
MAX_LENGTH, NUM_LABELS))
```

I was just wondering if any of you have experienced a similar problem and have figured out the reason why this happens.

Comment: Are you sure that `sequences` is 2D? And besides that, not like `(samples,1)`? Your padding function does not make it 2D at all. `pad_sequences` is not meant to do that.

Comment: `sequences` is not an array, but a list of lists (a list of sentences which are represented as lists). According to Keras documentation in the provided link (https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/), `pad_sequences` is exactly meant to turn a list of lists into a 2D array.

Comment: Ok... there are two possible things: some users made a single list (instead of list of lists), or some users have different keras versions. This function is not related to tensorflow.